# Sequelize - include getter returns in plain object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize class defined with a few virtual fields defined as follows:

```
class Post extend Sequelize.Model {
  get age () {
    return duration(this.get('createdAt'), new Date()).days
  }
}
```

(For brevity I've skipped the actual DB fields)

I'm running an Express app, I want these virtual fields to be sent to the client. When I call `post.get({ plain: true })` only the "real" DB fields are passed through. I get something like this:

```
{"createdAt": "2019-03-05T09:16:50.391Z"}
```

What's the best way of making the response more like this instead?:

```
{"createdAt": "2019-03-07T09:16:50.391Z", "age": 3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with was to declare the getter explicitly in the options, similar to KenOn10's suggestion, but in ES6 syntax. Here's the finished solution:

```
class Post extend Sequelize.Model {

  static init (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init(
      'age': {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get: function () { return this.getAge() }
      }
    }, { sequelize }
  }

  getAge () {
    return duration(this.get('createdAt'), new Date()).days
  }
}
```

A couple of things to note though:

- I've changed the getter function to an ordinary function called `getAge()`, because setting the `get` property in the schema also creates it as a getter. Therefore, if you call the getter within that function, it goes into a recursive loop and fills up the stack.
- The `get` option needs to be defined as a full function, because arrow functions don't have their own `this` context.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason to extend Model?  Using the getterMethods property seems to do what you ask.  For example:

```
sequelizeDB.define('my_printer_table',
  {
    printer_code    : {type: Sequelize.STRING,primaryKey: true},
    printer_name    : Sequelize.STRING
  },
  {
  getterMethods: {
    description() {
      return this.printer_code + ' ' + this.printer_name
    }
  }
});
```

Then, printer.get() results in:

```
Object {description: "ABC ABC Printing", printer_code: "ABC", printer_name: "ABC Printing"}
```

Comment: I extended Model because that's how all the models in this particular app are written (in this style: https://codewithhugo.com/using-es6-classes-for-sequelize-4-models/). It's within a project that's heavily object-based with lots of ES6, and consistency would be desirable.